# Lashon Hara That 3 people have already heard

Tags: lashon-hara-slander

Is it true that a derogatory statement that was already heard by 3 people or more, is not considered Lashon Hara? Such as saying that a Jew was charged with a certain crime, that more then 3 people know about? Please list sources.

Comment: Chapter 2 of Chafetz Chaim Hilchos Lasho Hora deals with the rule of Apei Tlasa - Lashon Hara that was said before 3 people. It can be found here with an English translation: https://www.sefaria.org/Chofetz_Chaim%2C_Part_One%2C_The_Prohibition_Against_Lashon_Hara%2C_Principle_2%2C_Opening_Comments.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en In short: it usually still is Lashon Hara.

Comment: @Salmononius2 you might consider posting an answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is indeed what the Talmud states:

**Arachin [15b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=15b&format=pdf)-[16a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=16&format=pdf)**

> אמר רבה רבה בר רב הונא כל מילתא דמיתאמרא באפי תלתא לית בה משום לישנא
>   בישא מ"ט חברך חברא אית ליה וחברא דחברך חברא אית ליה
>
> Rabbah son of R. Huna said: Whatsoever is said before three is not
>   considered slander. Why? Your friend has a friend, and your friend's
>   friend has a friend. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Arachin.pdf))

Various rabbinic authors have attached conditions and limitations to this rule, so you should perhaps be cautious before implementing it.