Lashon Hara in the modern day, when it can be immediately proven by public information
If someone has done something that makes them look bad, and there is proof - something very easy in the modern day, such as a video, or a message they wrote on social media - what is the halacha of showing people this proof? Does it count as Lashon Hara if there's no to'elet, or is this considered "public information"? I would also be glad to hear if someone could answer not just halachically, but what a yirat shamayim should do even lifnim mishurat hadin.
I'll give a couple of examples:

I buy a new car. One of my friends shows me that one of my other acquaintances has sent jealousy-driven messages to him and a few others, along the lines of "can you believe how irresponsible this guy is with money, we shouldn't let him near the shul bank account".

Was my friend allowed to show me that message? Am I allowed to show others? Does it make a different if I was, at the time, trying to get elected to the shul board or not? (note, this is not a personal question or looking for psak, just a hypothetical)

A bochur goes on holiday, and lets himself indulge a bit, and on his social media there are videos where he is speaking nivul peh.

Is one allowed to shared these videos with anyone?

Highly related: it's a machlochet between the Chofetz Chaim and the Gamarra: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94623/lashon-hara-that-3-people-have-already-heard

You might have opened up a can of worms here: is reposting someone else's poorly thought out post a form of lashon harah? (clearly not al pi ha din, but probably according to the Chofetz Chaim)

@יהושעק just in case, don't show anyone this question until we figure out if it is a good one, or makes me look stupid ;) FYI - reposting someone's posts is actually a very good case for my question - I want to explore exactly that sort of thing.

Note that in your car example it’s not Lashon Hara, but rather rechilut

@CuriousYid how so?

@RabbiKaii the friend who texted the mean stuff said lashon hara. But the guy who showed you the texts is guilty of rechilut. Rechilut means telling someone that someone else spoke bad of them

@יהושעק The Chafetz Chayyim's interpretation of this Gemara follows all the rishonim: מה שכתבתי בפנים לאו דעת יחידאה היא כי אם כל הראשונים מסכימים לזה. He mentions the most lenient opinion explicitly. See part 1 section 2 for details. In his introduction the Chafetz Chayyim says that the entire book is only the letter of the law, not strict opinions for pious people.

@ba so essentially you're telling me thay the Chofetz Chaim holds like the Chofetz Chaim? Does the Mishna Barura also hold like him? ;)

@יהושעק I mean only that it's not accurate to say that there's a machloket between the Chafetz Chayyim and the Gemara, or to say that the Chafetz Chayyim isn't the same as "al pi din." If there is a difference of opinion we would say he interprets the Gemara this way and someone else interprets it that way, or he says the law is this and someone else says the law is that, without dismissing him from being considered a posek :) but after you find a different opinion we'll agree it's a machloket

R. Daniel Feldman "The Right and the Good"? https://www.amazon.com/Right-Good-Halakhah-Human-Relations/dp/0765760517 Here are the issues of the chapters: 1. Embarassing others; 2. Derogatory Nicknames; 3. Honoring Oneself at Expense of Others; 4. Instigating and Perpetrating Disputes; 5. Honesty; 6. Lying for the Sake of Peace; 7. Vengeance and Grudges; 8. Favorable Judgements of Others; 9. Greetings. 10. The Bilateral Obligation of Forgiveness; 11. Hitting and Raising Hand in Violence; 12. Love and Hatred; 13.Aggressiveness and Insensitivity towards Others; 14. Concerns for Human Dignity.

If you yourself see something, no proof necessary, you cannot repeat it since we assume the guy did teshuva (beinoni). ditto if someone else posts it. If the guy himself posts something on social media, I would guess we can assume he has not done teshuva since he would have to pull it down (one who tells others his own (inter-god) sins is a sign of gaavah). if he doesnt pull it down hes prob a rasha and youre allowed to repeat it (with all other details of the hafetz haim of repeating...)

IIRC, The latter example is a Biblical prohibition of "אל תלך רכיל". 2 What is "public information" differ, if you're the one who [re] publishes it? If someone's fat, is it LH to say that he's fat because it is "public information"?
